# Excel - СУММПРОИЗВ с условием для одного из диапазонов

Tags: excel

Есть два столбца:

```
К-во | Цена
  2     50
 10     15
        40
```

Суть в том, что мне нужно посчитать итоговую стоимость, желательно без создания кучи дополнительных заранее высчитанных диапазонов.

Пустая ячейка в столбце Количество означает 1 штуку.

По идее, надо делать через `СУММПРОИЗВ(Цена; Количество)`, но проблема с пустыми ячейками в столбце кол-во.

Была идея пойти через что-то наподобие `СУММПРОИЗВ(Цена; ЕЧИСЛО(Количество)*Количество)`, но я не знаю, как прогнать диапазон через `ЕЧИСЛО` 'в цикле', поэтому результат там неправильный.

Мне бы что-то вроде `СУММПРОИЗВ(Цена; ЕСЛИДИАПАЗОН(Количество<>""; Количество; 1))`

Comment: Есть метка "excel-формулы". Считаю, что ее нужно добавить  к этому вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать формулу массива, вводится через `Cntrl+Shift+Enter`:

```
{=СУММПРОИЗВ(Цена; ЕСЛИ(Количество;Количество;1))}
```

[Формулы массива](http://exceltip.ru/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-excel-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB/)

Answer (score 1):

UPD: Методом тыка решение найдено, если есть менее странная формула, прошу поделиться)

`СУММПРОИЗВ(Цена * (Количество + (Количество="")))`

Comment: =СУММПРОИЗВ(цена;количество+(количество="")) - в таком варианте работает быстрее

Answer (score 1):

Формула массива (ввод тремя клавишами *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*):

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИ(количество;количество;1)*цена)
```

Оптимальнее:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(количество;цена)+СУММЕСЛИ(количество;"";цена)
```

Правильнее - это когда данные правильные )

Выделить диапазон *количество*, инструмент *НАЙТИ/ЗАМЕНИТЬ*:

*НАЙТИ* - ничего не пишем, *ЗАМЕНИТЬ - 1* (единица), *ОК*.

Теперь данные в полном порядке и не нужно придумывать костыли.